# Material UI ExpandMoreOutlined icon not able to give the exact padding

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using ExpandMoreOutlined component to show arrow on my select component. I wanted some padding for the icon. So I gave like below using paddingRight:

```
import React, { useState, RefObject } from 'react';
import { Select as MuiSelect, MenuItem, OutlinedInput } from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandMoreOutlined from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMoreOutlined';

const MyExpandMoreOutlined = styled(ExpandMoreOutlined)({
color: colorPalette.primary[0].interaction,
paddingRight: '20px'
});

<MuiSelect value={value}
id="storyBookSelect"
onChange={handleChange}
IconComponent={MyExpandMoreOutlined}
className={classes.select}
input={}
MenuProps={{
anchorOrigin: {
vertical: "bottom",
horizontal: "left"
},
transformOrigin: {
vertical: "top",
horizontal: "left"
},
getContentAnchorEl: null
}}
>
{menuItems}
```

But when I click the select to choose one selectItem. Down arrow Icon became up arrow. And the padding I gave in the right is applied to the left.

Seems there is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug; it's just the way it is designed to work. The icon [gets rotated 180 degress](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.2/packages/material-ui/src/NativeSelect/NativeSelect.js#L80) when the select is open. When you have padding as part of the icon, then the padding also gets rotated.

If you don't want this rotation, then you can override the transform as shown below:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ExpandMoreOutlined from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMoreOutlined";

const MyExpandMoreOutlined = styled(ExpandMoreOutlined)({
  color: "green",
  paddingRight: "20px",
  "&.MuiSelect-iconOpen": {
    transform: "none"
  }
});
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <TextField
      SelectProps={{ IconComponent: MyExpandMoreOutlined }}
      select
      label="Sample"
      value={value}
      onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      variant="outlined"
      style={{ width: "200px" }}
    >
      <MenuItem value="1">Option 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value="2">Option 2</MenuItem>
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit no transform for select icon]

---

If you want the rotation and the padding, then you just need to flip the padding for the rotated case:

```
const MyExpandMoreOutlined = styled(ExpandMoreOutlined)({
  color: "green",
  paddingRight: "20px",
  "&.MuiSelect-iconOpen": {
    paddingRight: 0,
    paddingLeft: "20px"
  }
});
```

[image: Edit no transform for select icon]

Comment: If I want the rotation along with padding, any solution ?

Comment: @NagendraPrasaduGandla I've added to my answer.